# Refresh browser on save in a non-local setup

Tags: visual-studio-code, smarty, webdav

I'm searching for a plugin that can autorefresh a specific page in my browser when I press CTRL+S in Visual Studio Code.

I'm working in a SaaS platform and I have to use WebDav to acces some Smarty template files .
I can live synchronise a local file to the platform when I save the file in VS Code, but I have to manualy refresh the browser each time to see the changes.

There are plugins that can autorefresh on save, but they are used in a local development setup.
As far as I can see, I can't use these plugins, because I can't execute the template files localy. I just change and upload them to the platform and see the result in the live website.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with a browserextension:

- Chrome: [Autoreloader: reload tab on file change](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autoreloader-reload-tab-o/innoeeijgleieecngfliphpjchmcobok)
- Firefox: [FileWatcher](https://coolsoft.altervista.org/en/filewatcher#download)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).